# Spring MVC RestController 404 The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a simple 'hello world' application using Spring MVC.
My goal is to send a GET response and receive a text message, however it keeps returning 404 "The requested resource [/api/hello] is not available". What can potentially be wrong? Below is my code:

```
package org.example.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Config

```
package org.example.rest.configuration;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example.rest")
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC");
            dataSource.setUser("bestuser");
            dataSource.setPassword("bestuser");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.example.rest.entity");

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                "true");

        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        manager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

```
package org.example.rest.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MyConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.24.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2 (Ultimate Edition).
Server is Tomcat 9.0.71

Comment: Judging from JUnit version 3.8.1, which is from 2007 and 1.8 compile target (which is End-of-life already), the tutorial you are trying to follow is very outdated. Also is there a reason why you're trying Spring WebMVC without Spring Boot?

Comment: Thanks for replaying. 
JUnit is not used in the app, so I wasn't paying attention to that. I was trying Java11, but in vain. There is no particular reason for using only WebMVC, just wanted to figure out how it works as a part of my learning process.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If you don't have strict requirements on your stack, then I strongly suggest trying Spring Boot just to get you going. Their official documentation looks pretty bland, but it's not too bad if you actually read it: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Spring Boot is meant to help people start as fast as possible with the least amount of configuration, that's why it is the preferred way to start working with it. Taking each piece of the framework individually and trying to configure that can be quite challenging when just learning. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will start from there.